# Estrutura banco de dados contestação de notas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um sistema de atribuição de notas onde é permitido contestação, réplica e/ou tréplica, qual a melhor forma de armazenar no banco de dados?

1. Criar três tabelas (`contestacao`, `replica`, `treplica`)
2. Criar uma tabela com os 3 campos
3. Criar uma tabela com o campo `tipo`

Answer (score 3):

Depende do que você quer.

## Criar três tabelas (contestacao, replica, treplica)

Isto permite que sejam inseridas várias contestações, réplicas e tréplicas para cada nota (o que acredito que não é seu objetivo). O controle pelo sistema é maior, visto que são 3 tabelas, e se for o caso de trazer os registros em uma única consulta, pode forçar o sistema a fazer uso de *unions*, o que não é bom para o desempenho. Ótimo para os casos em que interessar acessar apenas uma tabela de cada tipo de cada vez.

## Criar uma tabela com os 3 campos

Para o escopo de negócio, creio que seja o mais adequado, considerando que cada nota pode ter apenas uma contestação, uma réplica e uma tréplica. É também o mais simples de obter e de atualizar, mas não serve para múltiplos registros de contestações, réplicas e tréplicas.

## Criar uma tabela com o campo tipo

Este caso é interessante quando se deseja economizar em número de consultas e minimizar a quantidade de *joins* usadas pelo sistema. Também é para o caso de o seu sistema permitir uma quantidade variável de contestações, réplicas e tréplicas. Pode ser necessário adicionar um índice por tipo, o que torna a tabela maior no banco de dados.

Comment: A respota do colega é muito boa. Não sou a favor de criar três tabelas porquê provavelmente elas teriam as mesmas tabelas relacionadas. Criar um campo TIPO é interessante. Aumentar o tamanho da base hoje em dia não é problema considerando o preço do storage. Sugiro ainda criar um campo (tipo PARENTID) para relacionar a nota original à sua réplica e a réplica à tréplica etc ou (Se houver problema de recursão com isso) você poderia ter uma tabelas de relacionamento de notas x notas